# Codeigniter - TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I am developing one system with Codeigniter. I want to generate Purchase Order in PDF and save in folder. So, I use TCPDF library for generating PDF. But I received following error.

```
**TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: http://localhost/new-esup/po/14-22-25-04-2015.pdf**
```

I used following code.

```
    <?php

    tcpdf();
    $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $title = "";
    $obj_pdf->SetTitle($title);
    $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', $title, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
    $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
    $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');
    //$obj_pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
    $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '5', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);
    $obj_pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);
    $obj_pdf->AddPage();
    $content = 'HTML Text'
         $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content, true, false, true, false, '');


        $path = base_url() . 'po/';
        $file_name = $rfq_row->rfq_id . '-' . $quote_row->quote_id . '-' . date('d-m-Y') . '.pdf';
        $full_path = $path . $file_name;
        ob_clean();
        $obj_pdf->Output($full_path, 'F');
?>
```

Can anyone help me. I waste my lots of time to solve this error.

Comment: Have you check your folder permission?

Comment: but I don't know how to check folder permission

Comment: chmod($full_path, 0755); write this code before ob_clean(); and try

Comment: It's still display same error

Comment: try to catch the exception ans print it

Answer (score 3):

Delete the condition 'if statement..' in the static function under tcpdf_static.php, it work's !!

```
public static function fopenLocal($filename, $mode) {
    /*if (strpos($filename, '://') === false) {
        $filename = 'file://'.$filename;
    } elseif (strpos($filename, 'file://') !== 0) {
        return false;
    }*/
    return fopen($filename, $mode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `FCPATH` instead of `base_url()`:

```
$obj_pdf->Output(FCPATH.'your/path/directory/filename.pdf', 'F');
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that **your file** is not open anywhere when you run script. if it's open somewhere else then TCPDF can't open it.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when the file (which is about to create) is already present at the directory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).